# MongoEngine: Documents disappear after allowing_inheritance

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have a MongoEngine Document that previously didn't allow inheritance.  I then wanted to inherit from it, so I set `{allow_inheritance:True}`.  As soon as I did that the existing documents for that model didn't appear anymore when calling `<myModel>.objects`.  If I momentarily set `{allow_inheritance:False}` then the documents come back.  Why would that be?

I'm using MongoEngine verison 0.8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  When using `allow_inheritance`, MongoEngine stores a special `_cls` field in the base document with the name of the class, or derived class.  So for your `BaseClass` it would store `"BaseClass"` as the value, and for your `DerivedClass` it would would store `"BaseClass.DerivedClass"` as the value.  But without `allow_inheritance` set initially, it does not have this special `_cls` field set.  So after setting `allow_inheritance` I had to go in to the mongo field manually (not through mongoengine) and perform an `update` to add the `_cls` field with the `BaseClass` value and then documents reappeared.